# UISegmentedControl not responding to touches

Tags: ios, iphone, uibarbuttonitem, uisegmentedcontrol, uitoolbar

I have a UISegmentedControl in an XIB file. I have placed it within a UIBarButtonItem, which in turn is placed inside a UIToolBar. The problem I am having is that the UISegmentedControl is not responding to touches even though I have connected to an IBAction method. Any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would check the following items:

1. Right click the element to make sure the `IBAction` connected
2. Make you don't have heavy operations on the main thread that may be causing the view to lag
3. Make you don't a clear view over the `UISegmentedControl`

Comment: Yes that was it. There was a transparent view in there. Thank you. :)

Comment: @RameezHussain glad to help! Could accept the answer if it was your solution?

Comment: Instead of a transparent view upon it. My case is that my segmented control's super view is smaller than its subviews. And this is why I can see my segmented control but can not touch it. Thanks for your hint. =)

Answer (score 0):

Make certain that "`.userInteractionEnabled`" on your segmented control is set to "`YES`".